# Http JSON Response of big size is trimmed

Tags: php, json, laravel, docker

I'm running a php laravel backend on a docker swarm stack with some other services (including a reverse proxy). Some of the GET requests of large response size are responded to with a trimmed JSON - specifically, the last 4-5 'xx"}]' characters are trimmed - leading to an error in parsing this JSON response at the frontend.

Here I'm documenting my environment, all the versions and the `tcpdump` result of different places the packets pass by through the system.

1. General Look on the system
   [(Image) System Diagram. A proxy container pointing to a web container, both use httpd as server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZXIH.png)
2. `docker -v`

```
Docker version 20.10.11, build dea9396
```

3. `httpd.conf` of proxy. [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/UTnYE9uK)
4. `httpd.conf` of web. [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ux2hGJGg)
5. `php.ini` of web. [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/B2BCy2zR)
6. Laravel version

```
Laravel Framework 9.15.0
```

7. `tcpdump` results:

- Leaving web container : fine and complete
- Entering proxy container : fine and complete
- Leaving proxy container : Trimmed

8. Attempts

- Tried to access the web container directly -> Still the reponse is trimmed at the receiver although it appears complete in tcpdump
- Tried restarting everything - including removing all images and building them again

Comment: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61147 seems to have a similar problem that was related to a firewall, can this be the case?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I would definitely ask this on [sf]

Comment: @matiaslauriti Actually did this. https://serverfault.com/questions/1102579/http-json-response-of-big-size-is-trimmed

Comment: @Arend You mean the firewall applied on the traffic coming out of the container ?

Comment: @HmanA6399 this is indeed how I understand this issue.